# Possible to sync bookmarks between ubuntu touch browser and Firefox?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, firefox, sync, browser

Is there any solution for syncing bookmarks between the Ubuntu touch default browser and a Firefox sync account or owncloud?

Answer (score 1):

Currently thrte is no way to sync the bookmarks in the default browser. This is due to the fact that you cannot add firefox account details on. Thia however would be a great feature and for that reason I would suggest you ceeate a feature request for this in Launchpad.